# Loading a class in a new namespace

Tags: php

I need to load a class declared as in a namespace, to be loaded in a different one.

Happens that the current app needs to load some classes from a children app containing a similar runtime.

Not sure if its possible...

Comment: To fully understand your issue, and being able to recommend a solution, please expand on _"Happens that the current app needs to load some classes from a children app containing a similar runtime."_. Showing us some actual examples of the code/namespaces you're talking about will also help.

Comment: Kinda hard to display without a huge amount of code. Say I have have \App\ClassA loaded by the loader and I need to load \App\ClassA from from a different codebase. Anyway to change the namespace of the second \App\ClassA at inclusion?

Comment: Now I am wondering how the composer loader can append a root namespace with the 'autoload' instruction...

Comment: I don't see how it could be done. If they have the same namespace and class name, how would any class that depends on the one you move into another namespace (like in other code in the same library) know about it? You would need to basically copy/paste all the code and manually change all references as well. Also, read through [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and you'll get some ideas of how you can post code without posting everything.

Comment: Yes I got confuse with the autoload from composer.
As to create minimal example, thanks for the tip. There is no straight code related to the problem, its more of a concept problem.
The other solution for me if namespace a immutable, is to generate a set of classes in a different namespace. That doable! Thanks for your help!